# Propositional logic and distributive law

Tags: propositional-calculus

I am having trouble trying to understand how this question passes from this point

$$
( ( p\vee q )\wedge  (p \vee \neg r  )  \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r ) ) \vee  ( \neg p \vee r  ) 
$$

**to this**
$$
(p\vee q \vee \neg p \vee r)\wedge(p \vee \neg r \vee \neg p \vee r)\wedge(\neg q \vee \neg r \vee \neg p \vee r)
$$

$$
T \wedge T \wedge T = T
$$

I'm sure it has to do something with the distribution law ($p\vee(q \wedge r) =(p\vee q)\wedge(p \vee r)$) but I'm confused on how it is applied. Can anyone give me a heads-up on where and how I should start expanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first formula is of the form
$$(A\land B\land C)\lor D$$
while the second one is
$$(A\lor D)\land(B\lor D)\land(C\lor D)\,.$$

Comment: Got it thanks!
One more question though. Applying the formula I get this
$
((p\vee q) \vee( \neg p \vee r))\wedge((p \vee \neg r )\vee(\neg p \vee r))\wedge((\neg q \vee \neg r) \vee (\neg p \vee r))
$

Does that mean I can remove the brackets and why?

Comment: Nevermind associative law sais yes. Thanks